# Export Web Part feature does not create a .WebPart file

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-parts

For some reason we can't export our ASP.NET Web Parts to a `.WebPart` file.

Background: we implemented ASP.NET Web Parts on our ASP.NET based landing page. Web parts can be configured using Web Part editor and these settings are re-used by many users. There is a web part Export feature we'd like to use (because re-configuring the web parts by hand is a chore) which is facilitated by setting `ExportMode=All`. Ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartexportmode?view=netframework-4.8

Once `ExportMode=All` is set the web part's Export link appears. When we click Export we get a confirm message "This Web Part Page has been personalized. As a result, one or more Web Part properties may contain confidential information. Make sure the properties contain information that is safe for others to read. After exporting this Web Part, view properties in the web part description file (.WebPart) by using a text editor such as Microsoft Notepad."

After clicking OK, no file is downloaded. The expectation is to have a `.WebPart` file download.

Answer (score 0):

Our Page declaration has an `Async="true"` attribute. After setting that to `Async="false"`

```
<%@ Page MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" ... Async="false" %>
```

The Export function worked and created a .WebPart file that we can import.